# Errors trying to connect to Ruby API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making my way through these instructions https://github.com/phifty/agraph/blob/master/README.rdoc

And I installed the gem fine, and the program seems to not be complaining after I require the gem.

The problem happens when tring to connect to that database with this code:

```
server = AllegroGraph::Server.new :username => "user", :password => "pass"
repository = AllegroGraph::Repository.new server, "test_repository"
repository.create_if_missing!
```

I am new to RoR so I think my question is silly, but when I just add this code, I get a syntax error.  When I add the `@` character at the beginning of a line to make it a variable, I also get errors.

How can I use this code as part of my Ruby script?  And what I am doing wrong?

The error I get is:

```
uninitialized constant HomeController::Allegrograph
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using rails 3 you need to add the gem to your Gemfile. If on rails 2 you need to require the gem.

If that doesn't work, try this

server = ::AllegroGraph::Server.new :username => "user", :password => "pass"

Comment: It is rails 3 and I had already added the gem to the gemfile.  Your suggestion worked.  What is the difference with the sytax?

Comment: :: in the front tells ruby to look for the constant in the top level namespace instead of the lexical scope you were in. It was looking for that constant inside HomeController, as you can see in the error message.